# Integer Iterator not showing last int

Tags: java

I have an Integer Iterator that is not showing last int in my table.

See the code :
**TestIter.java**

```
import java.util.Iterator;

public class TestIter<T> implements Iterator<T> {

    private T[] tab;
    private int index;

    public TestIter(T[] tab) {
        this.tab = tab;
        index = 0;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasNext() {
        return this.tab.length > index + 1 && this.tab[index + 1] != null;
    }

    @Override
    public T next() {
        System.out.println("Current index : " + this.index);
        return this.tab[index++];
    }
}
```

**Test.java**

```
public class Test {

public static void main(String[] args){
    Integer [] a = {1,2,3,4,5};
    TestIter<Integer> test = new TestIter<Integer>(a);
    test.forEachRemaining(System.out::println);
}
```

Output does show 1,2,3,4 but not 5.
I know this is normal behaviour (because 5 doesnt have a haveNext()) but how do I fix this ?

Comment: You have an off-by-one error and you add 1 to the index in the `hasNext()` method. Do you see some correlation? Note that `hasNext()` needs to return when `next` would pass and `false` when it wouldn't. Right now you implemented "are there 2 more values?".

Comment: I would generally rethink if your `!= null` check in the  `hasNext()` method is really a good idea. Why treat every null value as not being a real element and signaling the end of your iterable? An Integer array `{null,2,3,4,5}` would have no elements according to your iterator.

Answer (score 3):

What happens:

// formula = tab.length > index + 1

```
+-------+---------+-----------+------------+
| index | formula | hasNext() | print      |
+-------+---------+-----------+------------+
| 0     | 5 > 1   | true      | tab[0] = 1 |
+-------+---------+-----------+------------+
| 1     | 5 > 2   | true      | tab[1] = 2 |
+-------+---------+-----------+------------+
| 2     | 5 > 3   | true      | tab[2] = 3 |
+-------+---------+-----------+------------+
| 3     | 5 > 4   | true      | tab[3] = 4 |
+-------+---------+-----------+------------+
| 4     | 5 > 5   | false     | -          |
+-------+---------+-----------+------------+
```

How to fix it?

- Don't add 1 to the index.

Comment: I get it but how can I make it work properly ?

Comment: Easy: Select the `+ 1` and press delete, then repeat for the next `+ 1`. All done!

Comment: Sure but hasNext() on 4 should return false (tab[4] doesnt have next)

Comment: Actually, the way you implement it, it does. Your index points at index that will be printed, not at next index.

Comment: @RayanDev you can also start your indext at -1 `index = -1;` and change your return in next() to `this.tab[++index]` which should fix your issue and maybe makes more sense logically. Your index variable currently always points at the next element to be returned by next(). By changing it to initialize at -1 it would change to represent the last index you returned from the iterator. (The iterator for ArrayList actually has variables for both indexes, last returned and next to return)

Comment: @RayanDev: no, `hasNext()` with `index = 4` should return `true`, because the way your `next` is implemented right now `index` indicates the **index of the next item to be returned**. In other words: `hasNext` should return `true` as long as `index` points to a valid item. You **could** implement it in a way where `index` points to the *last* item returned (which is what OH GOD SPIDERS describes above), but it's important that you choose one way or another and use that in both `hasNext` and `next`. Right now you interpret `index` differently in the two methods.

Answer (score 0):

You can implement `hasNext()` however you want.  But it seems to me that the following is easier to follow:

```
@Override
public boolean hasNext() {
     return index < tab.length && tab[index] != null;
}
```

I would also suggest you put your iterator in a separate nested class. Then you can implement the `Iterable` interface and just return an instance of the class.  This will then allow you to use the enhanced for loop on instances of your class.

Using a class is important for another reason.  Once index is used up you have no way of iterating of the array gain since you can't reset the index.  The index should be initialized to 0 as an instance field of the nested class.

And lastly, you should not be testing against the size of the internal data structure but the number of elements in that structure. So even if your array is of length 100. You add an element you increment size. You remove an element, you decrement size. And you only compare index to size, not to 100 or whatever the array size is.

Comment: Uhm but the problem would be that hasNext() if index = 4 would return true while index 4 has no next

Comment: index == 4 will return true.  But the null test takes care of that.  So the hasNext will return false.  But more to the point.  You should not be testing against the size of the internal data structure but the number of elements in that structure.  So even if your array is of length 100. You add an element you increment size.  You remove an element, you decrement size.  And you only compare index to size, not to 100.

Comment: Thank you all for your answers. I think I will go with index = -1. That's sad there has to be a workaround here

Comment: @WJS `tab[4]` has the value `5` so the null check wouldn't take care of that and it wouldn't have to. Because the next() call after that would return `tab[index++]` with index 4, meaning it would return `tab[4]` and then post-increment the index to 5.

Comment: Unfortunately, I was  referring to the case when a null was at the end.  What's the matter, aren't you guys psychic!? :)   But you're right of course.